# Why read in role-id and write in secret-id in Vault AppRole auth method

Tags: security, hashicorp-vault, vault, hashicorp

I have a question about when we configure the approle auth method of the vault, After the configuration of the approle, we need the role-id and secret-id to obtain the token and to do the further vault operations.

1. `vault write auth/approle/role/test-role token_ttl=15m token_max_ttl=30m`
2. `vault read auth/approle/role/test-role/role-id`
3. `vault write -f auth/approle/role/test-role/secret-id`
4. `vault write auth/approle/login role_id=<role-id> secret_id=<secret-id>`

Why there is not a read operation on secret-id ??

can't we just do this: `vault read auth/approle/role/test-role/secret-id`

Any Reason behind doing this?, and why there is a write operation on secret-id??

Answer (score 2):

`secret_id` is somehow similar to a token: it is dynamic, TTLed and can (and should) be recreated with *write* multiple times. `role_id`, on the other hand, is a more static entity, something like a *username*.